# Making CIContext.render(CIImage, CVPixelBuffer) work with AVAssetWriter

Tags: avfoundation, core-graphics, metal, core-image

I want to use Core Image for processing a bunch of `CGImage` objects and turning them into a QuickTime movie on **macOS**. The following code demonstrates what's needed, but the [output contains a lot of blank (black) frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LcuY.jpg):

```swift
import AppKit
import AVFoundation
import CoreGraphics
import Foundation
import CoreVideo
import Metal

// Video output url.
let url: URL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("av.mov")
try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)

// Video frame size, total frame count, frame rate and frame image.
let frameSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 2000, height: 1000)
let frameCount: Int = 100
let frameRate: Double = 1 / 30
let frameImage: CGImage

frameImage = NSImage(size: frameSize, flipped: false, drawingHandler: {
    NSColor.red.setFill()
    $0.fill()
    return true
}).cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil)!

let pixelBufferAttributes: [CFString: Any]
let outputSettings: [String: Any]

pixelBufferAttributes = [
    kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB),
    kCVPixelBufferWidthKey: Float(frameSize.width),
    kCVPixelBufferHeightKey: Float(frameSize.height),
    kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey: true,
    kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: true,
    kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: true,
]

outputSettings = [
    AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.h264,
    AVVideoWidthKey: Int(frameSize.width),
    AVVideoHeightKey: Int(frameSize.height),
]

let writer: AVAssetWriter = try! AVAssetWriter(outputURL: url, fileType: .mov)
let input: AVAssetWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: outputSettings)
let pixelBufferAdaptor: AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: input, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: pixelBufferAttributes as [String: Any])

input.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true

precondition(writer.canAdd(input))
writer.add(input)

precondition(writer.startWriting())
writer.startSession(atSourceTime: CMTime.zero)

let colorSpace: CGColorSpace = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB) ?? CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let context = CIContext(mtlDevice: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!)

Swift.print("Starting the render…")

// Preferred scenario: using CoreImage to fill the buffer from the pixel buffer adapter. Shows that
// CIImage + AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor are not working together.

for frameNumber in 0 ..< frameCount {
    var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
    guard let pixelBufferPool: CVPixelBufferPool = pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool else { preconditionFailure() }
    precondition(CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(nil, pixelBufferPool, &pixelBuffer) == kCVReturnSuccess)

    precondition(CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, []) == kCVReturnSuccess)
    defer { precondition(CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, []) == kCVReturnSuccess) }

    let ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: frameImage)
    context.render(ciImage, to: pixelBuffer!)

    //  This fails – the pixel buffer doesn't get filled. AT ALL! Why? How to make it work?
    let bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!)!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self), count: CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(pixelBuffer!))
    precondition(bytes.contains(where: { $0 != 0 }))

    while !input.isReadyForMoreMediaData { Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 10 / 1000) }
    precondition(pixelBufferAdaptor.append(pixelBuffer!, withPresentationTime: CMTime(seconds: Double(frameNumber) * frameRate, preferredTimescale: 600)))
}


// Unpreferred scenario: using CoreImage to fill the manually created buffer. Proves that CIImage 
// can fill buffer and working.

// for frameNumber in 0 ..< frameCount {
//     var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
//     precondition(CVPixelBufferCreate(nil, frameImage.width, frameImage.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, pixelBufferAttributes as CFDictionary, &pixelBuffer) == kCVReturnSuccess)
//
//     precondition(CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, []) == kCVReturnSuccess)
//     defer { precondition(CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, []) == kCVReturnSuccess) }
//
//     let ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: frameImage)
//     context.render(ciImage, to: pixelBuffer!)
//
//     // ✅ This passes.
//     let bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!)!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self), count: CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(pixelBuffer!))
//     precondition(bytes.contains(where: { $0 != 0 }))
//
//     while !input.isReadyForMoreMediaData { Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 10 / 1000) }
//     precondition(pixelBufferAdaptor.append(pixelBuffer!, withPresentationTime: CMTime(seconds: Double(frameNumber) * frameRate, preferredTimescale: 600)))
// }


// Unpreferred scenario: using CoreGraphics to fill the buffer from the pixel buffer adapter. Shows that
// buffer from pixel buffer adapter can be filled and working.

// for frameNumber in 0 ..< frameCount {
//     var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
//     guard let pixelBufferPool: CVPixelBufferPool = pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool else { preconditionFailure() }
//     precondition(CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(nil, pixelBufferPool, &pixelBuffer) == kCVReturnSuccess)
//
//     precondition(CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, []) == kCVReturnSuccess)
//     defer { precondition(CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, []) == kCVReturnSuccess) }
//
//     guard let context: CGContext = CGContext(data: CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!), width: frameImage.width, height: frameImage.height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer!), space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue) else { preconditionFailure() }
//     context.clear(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: frameSize))
//     context.draw(frameImage, in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: frameSize))
//
//     // ✅ This passes.
//     let bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!)!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self), count: CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(pixelBuffer!))
//     precondition(bytes.contains(where: { $0 != 0 }))
//
//     while !input.isReadyForMoreMediaData { Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 10 / 1000) }
//     precondition(pixelBufferAdaptor.append(pixelBuffer!, withPresentationTime: CMTime(seconds: Double(frameNumber) * frameRate, preferredTimescale: 600)))
// }

let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

input.markAsFinished()
writer.endSession(atSourceTime: CMTime(seconds: Double(frameCount) * frameRate, preferredTimescale: 600))
writer.finishWriting(completionHandler: { semaphore.signal() })

semaphore.wait()

Swift.print("Successfully finished rendering to \(url.path)")
```

The following, however, works with `CGContext`, but I **need** `CIContext` **in order to make use of GPU**. The problem seems to be with pixel buffers provided by the `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor`'s buffer pool. Rendering `CIContext` into individually created buffers and appending them to the adapter works, but is highly inefficient. Rendering `CIContext` into buffers provided by the adapter's pool results in no data being written into buffer **at all**, it literally contains all zeroes as if two are incompatible! However, rendering using `CGImage` works, so as copying the data manually.

The main observation is that `CIContext.render` appears to work asynchronously or something goes wrong between the buffer getting filled and data being written into the video stream. In other words there's no data in the buffer when it gets flushed. The following is kind of pointing in that direction:

1. Removing buffer locking results in almost all frames being written, except for the first few, the above code actually produces a [correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eZsW.jpg), but with the actual data the behaviour is as described.
2. Using a different codec, like ProRes422, results in almost all frames being written correctly, with just a few blanks – also the above code produces [correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvSuh.jpg), but larger and complex images result in skipped frames.

What's wrong with this code and what's the right way to do it?

P.S. Most iOS examples use pretty much the same implementation and seem to work perfectly fine. I found a [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50633899/458356) that it might differ for macOS, but can't see any official documentation on this.

Comment: You need an autorelease pool around the main loop of frames there, your current code will just consume all memory until the device crashes.

Comment: Also, do not use kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, you should be using kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After speaking with Apple Developer Technical Support it appears that:

> Core Image defers the rendering until the client requests the access to the frame buffer, i.e. `CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress`.

So, the solution is simply to do `CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress` after calling `CIContext.render` as shown below:

```swift
for frameNumber in 0 ..< frameCount {
    var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
    guard let pixelBufferPool: CVPixelBufferPool = pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool else { preconditionFailure() }
    precondition(CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(nil, pixelBufferPool, &pixelBuffer) == kCVReturnSuccess)

    let ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: frameImage)
    context.render(ciImage, to: pixelBuffer!)

    precondition(CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, []) == kCVReturnSuccess)
    defer { precondition(CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, []) == kCVReturnSuccess) }

    let bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!)!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self), count: CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(pixelBuffer!))
    precondition(bytes.contains(where: { $0 != 0 }))

    while !input.isReadyForMoreMediaData { Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 10 / 1000) }
    precondition(pixelBufferAdaptor.append(pixelBuffer!, withPresentationTime: CMTime(seconds: Double(frameNumber) * frameRate, preferredTimescale: 600)))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For your use case it would be better to use the [pull-style APIs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetwriterinput/1387508-requestmediadatawhenready) of `AVAssetWriterInput` because you don't need to process any media in real-time (like you would when capturing from a camera).

So rather then pausing the thread when the input isn't ready, just wait for it to pull the next frame. Remember to also set `expectsMediaDataInRealTime` to `false` in this case.

I think the main problem with you current approach is that you pause the very thread that the video processing is happening in when the writer is not yet ready.

(By the way: you can create `CIImage`s with a solid color directly (`CIImage(color:)`); no need to create a `CGImage` first.)

Comment: Hey Frank! Appreciate the input. 1. I'm actually capturing parts of the screen and specific windows for post-processing the returned `CGImage` in real time, so that part is necessary. 2. Correct, but the same doesn't apply to `CGImage` when you uncomment the "working" part, which was left for convenience in case some one decides to play with the code. By the way, good point on pull vs. push, I had the same thought about this. While both approaches appear valid, pulling would require major rewriting, which I'd rather avoid, unless there's supporting evidence that it would solve the issue.

Comment: You can try the newish `CIRenderDestination` API: Create a `CIRenderDestination` from the pixel buffer and call `let task = context.startTask(toRender: image, to: destination)` on the `CIContext`. You can then explicitly call `waitUntilCompleted()` on the task object to make sure Core Image finished processing before you try to write the pixel buffer to the video file.

Comment: That looked very promising, unfortunately produces same result… damn! Came across a few logging statements while digging through CoreImage disassembly. Do you know if there are any env variables to trigger verbose logging?

Comment: I don't know, but that would be awesome… Have you put a break point at the point where you append the pixel buffers and inspected them with QuickLook? Would be interesting if those are black already.

Comment: Yes, just tried that + a few options. `CIContext.render` produces black pixels and no output. The entire pixel buffer is just zeroes right after the render. Creating new pixel buffer directly from `CGImage` data produces broken frames as if it's data gets partly released and parts of it become black. Finally `memcpy`ing `CGImage` data straight into the buffer works like in case with the `CGContext`, no artifacts, but slightly faster and the color planes are all mixed up.

Comment: Have you tried different format types? `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` for instance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192973/discussion-between-ian-bytchek-and-frank-schlegel).