# Wait on CIContext render tasks in a non-blocking way

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image, core-video

I am looking for a way to wait for a `CIContext` render to complete without blocking. For simplicity, here is an example where I render one `CVPixelBufferRef` to another `CVPixelBufferRef` using `CIImage` and `CIContext`. Obviously my actual pipeline would do more, but this is the simplest case.

```
CIContext *context = [CIContext new];
// sourceBuffer provided from something like a camera
CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:sourceBuffer];

CVPixelBufferRef output;
// pool was allocated elsewhere
CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, bufferPool, &output)
[context render:image toCVPixelBuffer:output];
```

The code as it is blocks until the render is complete, because `[CIContext render:toCVPixelBuffer:]` is blocking.

You can start the render task in a non-blocking way using `[CIContext startTaskToRender:toDestination:error:]`, like so

```
CIContext *context = [CIContext new];
// sourceBuffer provided from something like a camera
CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:sourceBuffer];

CVPixelBufferRef output;
// pool was allocated elsewhere
CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, bufferPool, &output)

CIRenderDestination *destination = [[CIRenderDestination alloc] initWithPixelBuffer:output];
[context startTaskToRender:image toDestination:destination error:nil];
```

This is halfway there, the call doesn't block, but I have no idea when the render task is finished. That API returns a [CIRenderTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cirendertask), but that only has a single instance method on it, which is of course `waitUntilCompletedAndReturnError`, which will block until the task is finished.

To be honest, besides providing a medium for an error callback I don't really understand the point of this API. Unless your pipeline doesn't need to know when the task is finished, you still have to block to get your results.

**So, my question: Is it possible to get the results of a `CIContext` render without blocking?**

Answer (score 2):

The first `render` call should actually not really be a blocking call. As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56334656/541016),

> "Core Image defers the rendering until the client requests the access to the frame buffer, i.e. `CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress`".

However, you can also use the `CIRenderDestiantion` API and make it async yourself like this:

```
CIRenderTask *task = [context startTaskToRender:image toDestination:destination error:nil];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    [task waitUntilCompletedAndReturnError: NULL];
    // do async stuff here, e.g. call a callback block
});
```

Comment: That's very interesting. When profiling my app, the render line specifically accounts for almost 80% of my total CPU usage. It seems like if it just deferred until the next time I needed to lock the frame buffer it would return instantly, and the CPU tax would be in the next pipeline stage (video encoder).