# How to render/export frames offline in Metal?

Tags: swift, 3d, avfoundation, metal

I'm new to Metal and I was able to achieve a simple simple scene Quad rotating on the screen, but I want to export a 1 minute video/frames without having to do in real-time. 
So think about the user just opens app and taps the 'export button' and the cpu/gpu goes full speed to output a 1 minute video/frames of the Quad rotating without previewing it.

I know how to convert frames to video using AVFoundation, but not my 3d scene into frames without doing it realtime.

can someone point me where to look?.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I adapted my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43860229/155187) and the Apple Metal game template to create [this sample](https://github.com/warrenm/MetalOfflineRecording), which demonstrates how to record a video file directly from a sequence of frames rendered by Metal.

Since all rendering in Metal draws to a texture, it's not too hard to adapt normal Metal code so that it's suitable for rendering offline into a movie file. To recap the core recording process:

- Create an `AVAssetWriter` that targets your URL of choice
- Create an `AVAssetWriterInput` of type `.video` so you can write video frames
- Wrap an `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` around the input so you can append `CVPixelBuffer`s as frames to the video
- After you start recording, each frame, copy the pixels from your rendered frame texture into a pixel buffer obtained from the adapter's pixel buffer pool.
- When you're done, mark the input as finished and finish writing to the asset writer.

As for driving the recording, since you aren't getting delegate callbacks from an `MTKView` or `CADisplayLink`, you need to do it yourself. The basic pattern looks like this:

```
for t in stride(from: 0, through: duration, by: frameDelta) {
    draw(in: renderBuffer, depthTexture: depthBuffer, time: t) { (texture) in
        recorder.writeFrame(forTexture: texture, time: t)
    }
}
```

If your rendering and recording code is asynchronous and thread-safe, you can throw this on a background queue to keep your interface responsive. You could also throw in a progress callback to update your UI if your rendering takes a long time.

Note that since you're not running in real-time, you'll need to ensure that any animation takes into account the current frame time (or the timestep between frames) so things run at the proper rate when played back. In my sample, I do this by just having the rotation of the cube depend directly on the frame's presentation time.

Comment: O_O thank you so much! this is going to be fun! I looked everywhere, but never found an example on offline rendering. thank you :D